# check if the first cell in the table has img tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML table, I need to get the corresponding fields if the first cell has `img` element.

**Table**

```
<table id="ImgtableID">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>img</th>
<th>Title</th>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td><img src=""/></td>
<td>Title</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src=""/></td>
<td>Title</td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>other value</td>
<td>Title</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src=""/></td>
<td>Title</td>
</tr>
</tbody>

</table>
```

I tried the below code but it didn't work:

```
$('#ImgtableID').find('tbody td:first-child').each(function() {

if ($('img',this).length > 0) // also "$this.find('img').length" is not worked
{

}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:first-child` is originally a CSS pseudo selector, in jQuery, you can just use `:first`

and, I think you should loop the `<tr>`, not the first `<td>`.

Try it:

```
$(function(){
    $('#ImgtableID tr').each(function() {
        if ($(this).find('td:first img').length > 0) {
            $(this).css('color','limegreen');
            //or anything  you want
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: **https://www.bootply.com/TVfueIHPIA**

Comment: Both works boss. `:)` It's a selector in jQuery as well.

Comment: @PraveenKumar okay, I didn't know. Updated! :-)

Comment: I set this as an answer because the other answers include <th> thank you!

Comment: @M.Qassas My answer doesn't include `<th>`. 

Comment: Hi @PraveenKumar  First thank you for your helpful answer, second, please correct me if I am wrong! when I run code snippet it shows **no image**  for this  <th>img</th>  <th>Title</th> it should exclude it as Taufik show in his Fiddle (also Alexandru-Ionut Mihai code shows **false** for <th>).  by the way, I respect all answers so I upvote all helpful answers :)

Comment: @M.Qassas Got it now. But I am pretty sure, both the codes will display the same output. Check for yourself. :)

Comment: what's happening here? the asker was helped, so our job is done here :-) I've check your answer @PraveenKumar but you used too much functions while all of it can be just a simple selector, I think unneeded functions call could affect to performance. like `$(this).find("td").first().children("img").length` can be just `$(this).find('td:first img').length` like my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `find('tbody td:first-child')` **returns only one** node. I have looped like this, on the selector that gives multiple nodes:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#ImgtableID").find("tr").each(function () {
    if ($(this).find("td").first().children("img").length == 1)
      console.log("Found Image");
    else
      console.log("No Image");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<table id="ImgtableID">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>img</th>
      <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td><img src=""/></td>
      <td>Title</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src=""/></td>
      <td>Title</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td>other value</td>
      <td>Title</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src=""/></td>
      <td>Title</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('#ImgtableID').find('tbody td:first-child')` returns only first `td` from your table.

You should looking through all the `tr` rows from your table and `get` first `td` using `:first-child` **pseudo class** or using `eq` method.

> `eq` method reduces the set of matched elements to the one at the
>   specified index.

Using `eq` method.

```
let containsImage=$(this).find('td:eq(0) img').length>0;
```

```js
$('#ImgtableID').find('tbody tr').each(function() {
  let containsImage=$(this).find('td:first-child img').length>0;
  console.log(containsImage);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="ImgtableID">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>img</th>
<th>Title</th>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td><img src=""/></td>
<td>Title</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src=""/></td>
<td>Title</td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>other value</td>
<td>Title</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src=""/></td>
<td>Title</td>
</tr>
</tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select the `img` elements contained in the `td` elements that are first child of their containing `tr` element using this DOM selector:

```
tbody td:first-child img
```

And then it's not clear what you want to do with it.
If, for example, you want to get some value from the `td` element next to the one that contains the `img`,
you could get the `.parent()` of the `img`,
and then with `.next()` the next `td` element,
for example:

```
$('#ImgtableID').find('tbody tr td:first-child img').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).parent().next().text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("table tr:first-child td:first-child img").length > 0
```

OR
    $("#ImgtableID tr:first-child td:first-child img").length > 0 - for your id table

means that 
if first **td** tag of first **tr** tag of table contains **img tag** length will be more than 0